# Are node.js and V8 builtins written in JS or compiled and run as native code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

In node.js and I assume by extension V8, are built-ins (such as JSON, Math, etc)  native code residing in the interpreter or are they javascript code that gets interpreted the same way as the rest of user-written code?

So for example, does a call to `JSON.stringify(my_data)` jump to compiled machine code or does it just run more JS code?

Comment: As far as I know, v8 gives all the basic building blocks (types, data structures, execution engine and stuff) and all the ECMA Script specification's implementation is in JavaScript only.

Comment: There is no interpreter, all code is compiled to native before ran

Comment: Last I checked (which was some time ago) that's not strictly true.  it gets compiled on x86 but not on arm, which is what I happen to be using.  One can argue also weather that is interpreted or not given that no binary is saved and what happens is machine dependent.  I choose my phrasing ("... interpreted the same way as the rest...") carefully for that reason, but i guess we can still argue in spite of that.  I'll endeavor to be more pedantic in the future.

Comment: @user1816847 There has never been any interpreter, the closest thing you could confuse it with is an implementation a CPU architecture emulator  and running the generated native code through that I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be responsible for JSON stringification:
https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/v8/src/json-stringifier.h

Quickly browsing the repo will give you an idea of whats written in native code (and what's not):
https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/deps/v8/src

Answer (score 0):

Glancing at the V8 source code, I think it's a mix of both. JSON is backed by native code in [json-parser.h](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/json-parser.h); (at least some of) math is implemented as JavaScript in [math.js](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/math.js).